# angular-ui-bootstrap modal not passing back result

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am running into a problem with the modal service from Angular-ui-bootstrap. 
I have set up the modal according to the example on : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ but i can not get a result back from the modal if i remove the list items from the modal content and replace them with a text area and a different ng-model. I would setup a jsfiddle but i do not know how to include specific libraries (like angular-ui-bootstrap) that are necessary to show what i want.
I do have a screenshot of my modal : http://d.pr/i/wT7G.

Below is the code from my main controller, main view, modal controller and modal view:

main view code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="importSchedule()">import schedule (JSON)</button>
```

main controller

```
$scope.importSchedule = function() {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/importmodal.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        console.log('result: ' + result);
        // $scope.schedule = angular.fromJson(scheduleJSON);
    }, function () {
        console.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};
```

modal view

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Import schedule(JSON)</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" ng-model="schedule"></textarea>
  <pre>form = {{schedule | json}}</pre>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

modal controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('VMP')
    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

        $scope.schedule = '';

        $scope.ok = function () {
            console.log('schedule: ', $scope.schedule);
            $modalInstance.close($scope.schedule);
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What does the `console.log()` inside `$scope.ok` show? If it does indeed show the correct value, I would suggest wrapping your schedule data inside an object, to avoid any scope related issues:

```
$scope.schedule = { data: '' };
```

Then inside your modal view:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="15" ng-model="schedule.data"></textarea>
```

And your output:

```
$modalInstance.close($scope.schedule.data);
```

Comment: the console.log() inside the $scope.ok() function showed no result, at least not visible in the console. your way works although i don't understand why it does? Why does it not work to pass data around without encapsulating the data inside an object literal? is that something angular js specific that i missed?

Comment: I always finding myself linking to this guys blog: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Thanks, this clarified much!

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me as well.