# What's wrong with angular $modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i want to return some rezult from radioboxes from modal window. I used Angular bootstrap for this. So my code doesn t return me radiobox value after closing the modal window.

Template code:

```
 <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Вы уверены, что хотите удалить категорию?</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    Выбирете способ удаления
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="deleteType" value="this">
            Удалить категорию включая её подкатегории
        </label><br />
        <label>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="deleteType" value="select">
            Удалить категорию и выбрать новую для подкатегорий
        </label><br />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="ok()">Delete</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
$scope.delCat = function (index,el,current) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'view/category/dialog.html',
        controller: 'modalDialogController',
        size: 'sm',
        resolve: {
            deleteType: function () {
                return $scope.deleteType;
            }
        }
    });
    var deleteOne = function(){
        current.splice(index,1);
    }
    var deleteMore = function(){
        alert('asdfasd');
    }
    modalInstance.result.then(function (deleteType) {
        switch (deleteType) {
            case 'this':
                deleteOne();
                break;
            case 'select':
                break;
        }
    });
};
mainApp.controller('modalDialogController', function ($scope, $modalInstance, deleteType) {
    $scope.deleteType  = 'this';
    $scope.ok = function () {

            $modalInstance.close($scope.deleteType);

    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {

        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');

    };
});
```

Function $scope.ok() doesn t return value of $scope.deleteType after its closing.

Comment: You should have look into this http://stackoverflow.com/q/21691120/2435473

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3v00DmKDD4qHKBw9IN2R?p=preview)**. I've reproduced the modal with your code.

The value of the radio button, stored in `deleteType`, is correctly passed into the success callback of the `result` promise